# Why does the value of variable in a thread remains constant despite the thread running?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop

I am new to threading concepts in Java. I made a thread consisting of a method called timer() this method lessens the value of the variable 'time'. I dont know what I am doing wrong in this, The code is posted below:

```
package Threading;
/**
 * Threads are used to perform tasks cocurrently 
 * In this example we used Thread Class 
 * .start() is method use to run the method
 * .sleep is used for delay and so on
 */
public class Intro_using_Thread extends Thread {
    int time;


    public Intro_using_Thread(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    

    public void timer() {
        for (int i = time; i >= 0; i--) {
            time--;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Driver Class

```
package Threading;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Threads are used to perform tasks cocurrently In this example we used Thread
 * Class .start() is method use to run task
 */
public class Intro_using_thread_run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Intro_using_Thread timerobj = new Intro_using_Thread(200000);
        timerobj.start();
        while (timerobj.time!=0) {
            choice = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The time is = "+timerobj.time);
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

OUTPUT

[The Output is in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3dXo.png)

I dont know why Stack overflow does not lemme add pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start() method causes the thread to begin execution. JVM calls the run() method of the newly started thread.
So you have to rename timer() function to run().

```
package Threading;
/**
 * Threads are used to perform tasks cocurrently 
 * In this example we used Thread Class 
 * .start() is method use to run the method
 * .sleep is used for delay and so on
 */
public class Intro_using_Thread extends Thread {
    int time;


    public Intro_using_Thread(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    

    public void run() {
        for (int i = time; i >= 0; i--) {
            time--;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update : Edited the explanation to be more clear.**

Comment: Re, "When you call...start(), it...calls run()." That's true, but saying it that way could mislead a beginner. The `run()` call happens _because of_ the `start()` call, but it does not happen _inside_ the `start()` call: It happens in a different thread.

Comment: Does that mean that simply calling timerobj.run() will run that function on same thread? Does this mean that after running start() once makes a different thread and after that every run() will call that new thread?

Comment: Solomon : Updated the answer to be more clear.

Comment: huzaifa :
A) Does that mean that simply calling timerobj.run() will run that function on same thread?  -- Yes. timerobj is still a java object and you can call its functions.

B) Does this mean that after running start() once makes a different thread and after that every run() will call that new thread? -- start() creates a new thread and calls run() method on the new thread.